# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data files\\URL_ID_1.txt'

Tags: python, web, google-drive-api, drive, google-drive-shared-drive

```
# Folder Path
path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data files"
  
# Change the directory
os.chdir(path)
  
# Read text File
def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        info=f.read()
        stop_words(info)
  
  
# iterate through all file
    for file in os.listdir():
        # Check whether file is in text format or not
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
      
            # call read text file function
            read_text_file(file_path)
```

I get this error:

```
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-139-07ff61fe2c38> in <module>()
         22 
         23         # call read text file function
    ---> 24         read_text_file(file_path)
    
    <ipython-input-139-07ff61fe2c38> in read_text_file(file_path)
         10 
         11 def read_text_file(file_path):
    ---> 12     with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
         13         info=f.read()
         14         stop_words(info)
    
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data files\\URL_ID_1.txt'
```

Comment: The error is clear: that file does not exist.  What is your question?

Comment: actually, file exists URL_ID_1.txt in the folder that is the problem I am facing

Comment: Try changing `file_path = f"{path}\{file}"` to use a forward slash instead of backward slash.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening due to linux, windows inconsistency, you should add your file path as

file_path = os.path.join(path,file)